# Setting up the server TFS server url on a virtual machine

Tags: tfs

I am using a virtual server hosted anywhere (the virtual machine has Windows Server 2012 Datacenter R2 installed), but is not an domain controller. Now I installed Team Foundation Server 2015 RC (it's the release candidate but I think I will get similar problems with other versions) and the URL's are populated using the machine Name.

For example if my domain is abc.de, and my hostname is vmd12345, then the populated urls are something like this:

http://vmd12345:8080/tfs

Accessing repositories from visual studio is not a problem, but when I do some actions (for example view build logs), the web application tries to request vmd12345, what in fact is not accessible outside of the server. I tried to change the urls using the change url button in the TFS admin console, but if I do the system ask for a username and password and I do not know which user account is required.

Trying to change the URL's using the admin console failed cause the system has asked by to enter the credentials (I guess the credentials of the configured service user is ment), but the credentials did not work.

Further investigations shows that this is caused by an IIS problem of the webpage the TFS deploys into the IIS. If I connect at localhost, the credentials of the user were accepted, using the domain name the credentials was not accepted. Any Idea of what the problem can be?

Comment: What do you want the urls to be like?

Comment: You ment, how the url's should look like? a url like http:mydomain.com:8080/tfs is suffient, very well would be if tfs.mydomain.com. But my first suggestion is still fine....

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the administration console on the TFS server and on the "Application Tier" node click "change URL". At the public up only...

Comment: As I wrote what you are suggesting is exactly what I did. Please take a look at my question details to find further investigation details!

Comment: The answer is correct, you just need someone who is in tgebAdmin Console users...who installed tfs? They would have been added by default...

Comment: I installed the TFS myself. The Administrator account an my custom account are "Administrator console users". Where to find the "tgebAdmin Console users".